# how to remove an item from sparse array if the key is present it

Tags: java, android

As sparseArray has some more features than hashmap I'm using it but the issue is it does not provide a method which can check if the key is present in it. how can we simply check the key is present it or not, like a map.containsKey(key)like this Map method.

```
 if(sparseArray!!.size()>0) {
    sparseArray?.removeAt(sparseArray!!.indexOfKey(id.toInt()))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(sparseArray.size() > 0  && sparseArray.indexOfKey(int) >= 0) {
   // Your code... 
}
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#indexOfKey%28int%29

> Returns the index for which keyAt(int) would return the specified key,
>   or a negative number if the specified key is not mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/20146261) :

```
if(sparseArray.indexOfKey(int) < 0) {
   //Item does not exist. Do something relevant 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by wether value return by given key is null or not

Consider following answer

> Use if(get(key) != null) as a quick replacement for contains().

SparseArrays map integers(key) to Objects(Values). Unlike a normal array of Objects, there can be gaps in the indices.